# prevent Sympy from simplifying expression python after a substitution

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using Sympy to substiture a set of expressions for another using the Subs function, and I would like for the program not to rearrage or simplify the equations.
i.e if i were substituting `x+y` for `a` in

`a+b+c+a` to return `x+y+b+c+x+y`

Does anyone know of a way to perform this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to do it is to do `Add(x, y, b, c, x, y, evaluate=False)`, which unfortunately isn't very easy to work with.

Comment: Where can I find the doc for this function Add? Goggling isn't very helpful in this case!

Comment: `Add` is the class that is created when you have an addition in SymPy. `x + y` is translated internally to `Add(x, y)`.  The best resource for this is the new tutorial I am writing: http://docs.sympy.org/tutorial/tutorial/manipulation.html.

Comment: There's a new method now! I'm commenting you on this because you feel the pain of having to use these classes for basic operations like me! I came across a method that doesn't have to use those. It's not even on their websites, but is documented in the code. I came across it as pure coincidence, and now this opens up to a lot of new things for me! See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a better way of going about this rather than using classes like `Add`. What if you have an expression that has a lot of operations? Using these classes would be cumbersome.

Instead, we can use the `evaluate` function, which is used inside of a context manager. Here is an example of an expression that has quite a few operations, but we can substitute without the expression immediately simplifying/evaluating.

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
expr = x**2*sp.sqrt(y**2 + 45*x)
print(expr)

# Substitute without evaluating
with sp.evaluate(False):
    expr_subs = expr.subs([(x, 2), (y, 7)])
    print(expr_subs)
print(expr_subs.doit())
```

This will output what is desired:

```
x**2*sqrt(45*x + y**2)
2**2*sqrt(7**2 + 45*2)
4*sqrt(139)
```

Notice that any substitution that occurs inside the context manager will not evaluate, but it will if it is outside. Use the `doit()` method to evaluate/simplify the expression, but it will raise an error if `doit()` is called inside the context manager. Note that the documentation for this function (located in the `parameters.py`) warns us that this functionality is experimental.

**Your Case**

---

For your specific case,

```
import sympy as sp

x, y, a, b, c = sp.symbols('x y a b c')

with sp.evaluate(False):
    expr = a + b + c + a
    expr_sub = expr.subs(a, x + y)
print(expr_sub)
```

Output:

```
c + b + x + y + x + y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list/tuple unpacking to automate this as well

```
lst = (1,4,5,6, nsimplify(1/2))
lstadd = Add(*lst, evaluate=False)
display(lstadd)
display(nsimplify(lstadd))
display(lstadd.evalf())
```

[image]